# How to generate Regular Expression that doesn't contain any white space at all and even at the beginning or the end of the string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried this but it doesn't work : [Demo Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/p31F9RJ5hhRkw2oh1h8D?p=preview)

```
<form name="myform1">
  valid? {{ myform1.$valid }}
  <input type="text" name="username1" ng-model="username1" ng-pattern="/^\S.*?\S$/" required/> ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
</form>
```

Comment: you could also use split() and join() || https://jsfiddle.net/maio/t06zx2rp/

Comment: ya thank you. but i'm searching for Regular Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\S*\S+\S*$
```

It will detect whitespace between string.
You can remove starting and ending whitespace by

```
$scope.username1.trim();
```